# null reference exception in the code

Tags: c#, xml, c#-3.0, nullreferenceexception

I am getting NullReferenceException error on "_attr.Append(xmlNode.Attributes["name"]);".

```
namespace SMAS
{
class Profiles
{
    private XmlTextReader _profReader;
    private XmlDocument _profDoc;

    private const string Url = "http://localhost/teamprofiles.xml";
    private const string XPath = "/teams/team-profile";

    public XmlNodeList Teams{ get; private set; }
    private XmlAttributeCollection _attr;

    public ArrayList Team { get; private set; }

    public void GetTeams()
    {
        _profReader = new XmlTextReader(Url);
        _profDoc = new XmlDocument();

        _profDoc.Load(_profReader);
        Teams = _profDoc.SelectNodes(XPath);

        foreach (XmlNode xmlNode in Teams)
        {
            _attr.Append(xmlNode.Attributes["name"]);
        }
    }
}
}
```

the teamprofiles.xml file looks like

```
  <teams>
    <team-profile name="Australia">
      <stats type="Test">
        <span>1877-2010</span>
        <matches>721</matches>
        <won>339</won>
        <lost>186</lost>
        <tied>2</tied>
        <draw>194</draw>
        <percentage>47.01</percentage>
      </stats>
      <stats type="Twenty20">
        <span>2005-2010</span>
        <matches>32</matches>
        <won>18</won>
        <lost>12</lost>
        <tied>1</tied>
        <draw>1</draw>
        <percentage>59.67</percentage>
      </stats>
    </team-profile>
    <team-profile name="Bangladesh">
      <stats type="Test">
        <span>2000-2010</span>
        <matches>66</matches>
        <won>3</won>
        <lost>57</lost>
        <tied>0</tied>
        <draw>6</draw>
        <percentage>4.54</percentage>
      </stats>
    </team-profile>
 </teams>
```

I am trying to extract names of all teams in an ArrayList. Then i'll extract all stats of all teams and display them in my application. Can you please help me about that null reference exception?

Comment: Two tips to avoid NullReferenceException: 1) **always** initialize fields; 2) **avoid** using `null`.

Comment: To solve, i did what ReSharper told me to do 

        foreach (XmlNode xmlNode in Teams) 
        { 
            _attr.Append(xmlNode.Attributes["name"]); 
        }

I added a null check for Teams before foreach loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cant see where you initialise `private XmlAttributeCollection _attr;`

you can try

```
 _profDoc.Load(_profReader);
_attr =  _profDoc.DocumentElement.Attributes;
```

Comment: How should i initialize it? i can not initialize it as

      private XmlAttributeCollection _attr = new XmlAttributeCollection()

Answer (score 3):

You never initialize `_attr`. It's a null reference.

Comment: With what value should i initialize it?

Comment: apologies, i accidently edited this answer rather than my own

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, you have to initialize _attr.

With what value?

A [`XmlAttributeCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlattributecollection.aspx) is returned by [`XmlElement.Attributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlelement.attributes.aspx). If what you want is the attributes of an element, you can just use that property. If what you want is a "collection of `XmlAttribute`" but not forcibly a `XmlAttributeCollection`, you can declare it like this:

```
ICollection<XmlAttribute> _attr = new List<XmlAttribute>();
```

And then use [`ICollection<T>.Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/63ywd54z.aspx) instead of `Append`.

Or, use LINQ:

```
_attr = (from node in Teams
        select node.Attributes["name"]).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like you ever assign anything to `_attr`, so of course it'll be `null`.